# Resolving Fatal status in Supervisor and Django

Tags: django, ubuntu, gunicorn

I am using Digital Ocean Ubuntu server to deploy my Django project and follow this guide to set it all up: [A Complete Beginner's Guide to Django - Part 7](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/10/16/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-7.html#tracking-requirements)

I am the process of configurig Gunicorn and Supervisor and I get the following error:

[image]

I am logged in as non-root but sudo user that I have created called betofolio. My django project is called betofolio.

Below is a screenshot of what my folders look like:
[image]

Following the steps from the tutorial:

Create a new file named gunicorn_start inside /home/betofolio:

```
vim gunicorn_start
```

I insert the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="betofolio"
DIR=/home/betofolio/betofolio
USER=betofolio
GROUP=betofolio
WORKERS=3
BIND=unix:/home/betofolio/run/gunicorn.sock
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=betofolio.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=betofolio.wsgi
LOG_LEVEL=error

cd $DIR
source ../venv/bin/activate

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DIR:$PYTHONPATH

exec ../venv/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $WORKERS \
  --user=$USER \
  --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=$BIND \
  --log-level=$LOG_LEVEL \
  --log-file=-
```

Then I save and exit.

Make this file executable:

```
chmod u+x gunicorn_start
```

Create two empty folders, one for the socket file and one to store the logs:

```
mkdir run logs
```

Configuring Supervisor

Create an empty log file inside the /home/betofolio/logs/ folder:

```
touch logs/gunicorn.log
```

Now create a new supervisor file:

```
sudo vim /etc/supervisor/conf.d/betofolio.conf

[program:betofolio]
command=/home/betofolio/gunicorn_start
user=betofolio
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/betofolio/logs/gunicorn.log
```

Then:

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo supervisorctl update
```

Now check the status:

```
sudo supervisorctl status betofolio
```

I get:
[image]

I am new to linux and networking, so I am not sure how to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

I was following the same guide, and ran into the same problem. What solved it for me was realizing I didn't have gunicorn installed in my virtual environment. I had done a `pip3 install gunicorn`, but you need to do `pip install gunicorn`. You may have to say sudo before if it says you don't have permission (`sudo pip install gunicorn`)

1. go into the logs folder, and open gunicorn.logs. This file is in /home/(user)/logs, and type `less gunicorn.logs` to see it. It will show you why it's failing. In my case it said it couldn't find gunicorn in the location I had specified within the gunicorn_start file.
2. Make sure you have the virtual environment activated The command line turns into `(name of virtual env) $...`
3. cd into /home/(user)/(venv)/bins, and type `ls` to see the files in the directory, and see if gunicorn is in there.

After fixing this it still wouldn't run, and I realized in the log files I had some typos in the gunicorn_start file, so that logs file is very handy to troubleshoot.